# Как найти файлы дубликаты в двух разных папках?

Tags: linux, diff

У меня есть две папки с большим количеством файлов в одной и в другой папках (DIR1 и DIR2), так получилось что некоторые файлы уже были в папке DIR1 и снова появились в папке DIR2, теперь мне нужно совместить эти папки и удалить повторяющиеся файлы из папки DIR1, какой командой это можно сделать ?

Comment: вы определитесь, пожалуйтса, что именно вам нужно: совместить два каталога или удалить повторяющиеся файлы из одного из них (эти задачи взаимоисключащие). если первое — то это банальное копирование, если второе — то тут одной командой не обойдёшься: надо ж для начала ещё найти все эти повторящиеся файлы/каталоги.

Comment: найти дубликаты поможет команда `fdupes DIR1 DIR2 -r` (ее обычно нет в поставке по умолчанию, но apt/yum знают, что делать)

Comment: Благодарю, команда fdupеs то что нужно